# chat com faye, rails e heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Implementei um chat que funciona 100% localmente.
Porém ao subir a aplicação para o heroku, o chat não funciona.
Então segui esse tutorial http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-private-pub-on-heroku/ e quando acesso a página do chat, recebo a seguinte mensagem:
 `Sure you're not looking for /faye ?`

Preciso configurar algo no heroku? Pesquisei bastante porém não encontrei nada claro.

Obrigado

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse add-on para usar Faye no heroku: https://messagerocket.co

Comment: Ou tente com action cable do Rails 5: https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

Comment: Acabei implementando com action cable. Obg pessoal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo com base nos comentários:

Tente trabalhar com Action Cable do Rails 5
https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

Websocket nativo no Rails.